# How can the time complexity (asymptotically) be equal for these functions?

Tags: algorithm

They differ in actual running time I know but using the concept I cannot determine, since the codes are drastically different in execution, how they have the same time complexity.

How come

```
void fun(){
    int i, j;
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++){
        for (j=1; j<=log(i); j++){
            printf("GeeksforGeeks");//prin tit
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
void fun2(){
    int i, j;
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++){
        for (j=1; j<=log(n); j++){
            printf("GeeksforGeeks");//print it
        }
    }
}
```

are asymptotically the same and have a time complexity of `O(logn!)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that the summation ∑ i to n (logi) is O(nlogn)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21152609/show-that-the-summation-%e2%88%91-i-to-n-logi-is-onlogn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of steps for `fun` is O(sum of log(i) for i from 1 to n) which is the same as O(log(n!)).

The number of steps for `fun2` is O(n log(n)).

Now [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) tells us that this is actually the same.

Comment: yep! `log2(n!) = Θ(n · log2(n))`   you could look at this as i = `O(n)` and therefore they behave the same.